# React-select multiple drop downs onChange implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Using react-select implemented a dynamic dropdown based on an array field in my Mongo, like so.

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'


  const NonFormikSelect = (props) => {

    const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([])

        let options1 = props.member.members.map(member => ({
            label: member.MemberName,
            value: member.MemberName
        }))

        console.log(options1)

      const selectChangeHandler = (event, numberofgroups) => {
       
      }

          const newValues = props.nogot.tournament.TournamentGroups.map((numberofgroups) => {
        return (
            <Select
            key={numberofgroups}
            name={numberofgroups}
            isMulti
            options={options1}
            value={numberofgroups in selectedOptions ? selectedOptions[numberofgroups]: ""}
            onChange={(event) => selectChangeHandler(event, numberofgroups)}
             />         
        )
    })

    return (
        newValues
    )
      }

  export default NonFormikSelect
```

my struggle is with the change handler function. i have tried multiple combos and gone through the multiple documents but unable to crack the design I want. Here is my state declaration in this component

const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([])

Here is the functionality I desire on onChange.

Assumption - my input array to the map function has 2 elements so it means 2 select drop downs will be pushed on the front end and the values in the drop down will be coming through another options1 object. This has a label and value key pair, as expected by react-select. Lets assume there are 10 key value pairs inside the object.

When the user open the form he is greeted with 2 drop downs. if he selects 3 names in the first drop down, then I want those names out of the second drop down. In the second dropdown lets say he selects. All 8 values will then need to be lifted up to the parent component, where onSubmit I am fetching a API and updating my collection.

Is this doable? I have run out of ideas. My change handler function is now empty hence not posting anything here

Comment: So you're trying to filter out previous values of one select array from the values of the 2nd array conditionally?

Comment: yes sir if that is possible please. my first select has say "John", "Joe" and "Joel". I select John. so the next select should only have Joe and Joel. and when i click Submit. All values selected by user of both select items should be pushed to the parent

Comment: So the 1st select is the entire array, and then the 2nd select is just the unused values from the first?

Comment: yes sir tht was the desire

Comment: Are you generating the select fields in React, or in the HTML?

Comment: in react. Just above in the same component. let me update the entire code

Comment: the selectChangeHandler I believe should do this logic. I deleted everything I wrote earlier, out of frustration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a cascading select .

```
import "./styles.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

const allOptions = [
  {
    label: "john",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "joe",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: "joel",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "jackie",
    value: 4
  }
];

const generateInitialState = (numberOfSelects) =>
  numberOfSelects.map((item) => null);

const CustomSelectComponent = ({ value, options, onSelect }) => {
  return (
    <Select
      value={value}
      options={options}
      isMulti
      onChange={onSelect}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState(() =>
    // increase the array elements to add more select fields
    generateInitialState(["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"])
  );

  const onSelectValues = (value, index) => {
    // clone state
    const clonedSelectState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectState));

    clonedSelectState[index] = value;
    setSelectState(clonedSelectState);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {selectState.map((selectCount, index) => {
        const options = getOptionsToRender(selectState, allOptions);
        return (
          <CustomSelectComponent
            value={selectState[index]}
            options={options}
            onSelect={(value) => onSelectValues(value, index)}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const getOptionsToRender = (allSelectedOptions, allOptions) => {
  // convert [[{}, {}], [{}]] -> [{}, {}, {}]
  const filteredOptions = allSelectedOptions.flatMap((options) => options);

  const optionsToRender =
    filteredOptions.length > 0
      ? allOptions.filter(
          (option) =>
            !filteredOptions.some(
              (selectOption) =>
                option && selectOption && option.value === selectOption.value
            )
        )
      : allOptions;

  return optionsToRender;
};
```

[Cascading Select Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-field-ovx89?file=/src/App.js:23-970)

Comment: so just to build on that Shyam, like I said the number of select items depends on the length of the array coming via props. Ho w will i cater this for ever changing dynamic size array?

Comment: can you add the shape of your dynamic array ?

Comment: its a simple array as such ["Group 1 ", "Group 2"]. But the value inside the array can be ["Group 1] or can be ["Group 1 ", "Group 2", "Group 3"]. All coming from upstream admin forms that I already built. I am mapping over this array and based on the number of elements in this array, I want the number of Select items displayed

Comment: Edited my answer and the sandbox with a working example .

Comment: took me about 2 hours to understand and implement it @shyam , but it worked like a dream :). thanx a ton